# Customize output for odd column using GROUP BY of mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the `daywise` table in MySQL which contain data

```
id   numbers    datetime                info
-----------------------------------------------
1    10         2018-04-20 07:00:00     Run
2    15         2018-04-20 08:20:00     Slow
3    20         2018-04-21 07:00:00     Fast
4    22         2018-04-22 07:50:00     Fast
5    07         2018-04-23 06:00:00     Fly
6    00         2018-04-22 10:00:00     Slow
7    06         2018-04-21 16:00:00     Avg
8    08         2018-04-22 22:00:00     Finish
```

Now I want this output

```
Count(numbers)      date          info
---------------------------------------------
25                  2018-04-20     Slow
26                  2018-04-21     Avg
22                  2018-04-22     Finish
07                  2018-04-23     Fly
```

I have designed this query

```
SELECT COUNT(numbers), DATE(datetime) as date, info
FROM daywise
GROUP BY date
```

So using this query first two columns are perfect but for column `info`, mySQL is randomly selecting data from `info` column. I want that cell's data which have latest datetime. So for `2018-04-20` latest `info` is **Slow**, for `2018-04-21` latest `info` is **Avg** and so on..

Comment: What version of MySQL are you  using? Since version 8 MySQL supports window functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Join with condition `datetime_max`?

```
SELECT COUNT(numbers), MAX(datetime) as datetime_max, DATE(datetime) as date,
d2.info as info

FROM daywise d1
LEFT JOIN daywise d2 ON d2.datetime = d1.datetime_max
GROUP BY d1.date
```

This require your `datetime` field to be unique to get latest `info` field;

Answer (score 0):

Use the below SQL.

```
SELECT  COUNT(numbers) as numbers,
    DATE(datetime) as date,
    (select info from daywise
       where datetime = MAX(d1.datetime)) as info
FROM daywise d1
GROUP BY date(datetime)
```